# send file to android device

Tags: java, android

I need to send a few strings from a java project (Windows or Ubuntu) to an Android device via  WiFi means. I found a  few sources on how to send files from Android device to Android device but I didn't find anything cross platform. Can someone suggest me a way to do it, or a lead about where to look ?

I am open to alternate methods, but as always the simplest the better.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest send it through TCP connection.

Because Both Java and Android have ServerSocket class and Socket class.

You can set your computer to be host by using ServerSocket and your Android device to be client by using Socket.

Then after connection, you can use getInputStream() and getOutputStream() methods of Socket to transfer data, including Strings, Objects and even Files with suitable combination of FileInputStream,ObjectOutputStream etc.

Comment: I tried your method, it seems to work. I found a sample code to send stuff from a java project server to a java project client and tried to adapt the client to android. I got the communication working by sending a string but I do not understand how to manipulate their interaction well. Can you point me to a tutorial or something like that ? Thanks

Comment: I assume you want to send strings between Android and Java via Wifi.
Here is one good example http://zerioh.tripod.com/ressources/sockets.html
The communication continue until the client say bye.
Instead of ObjectInputStream and ObjectOutputStream, you can use Scanner and PrintWriter for String communication.

Answer (score 1):

I would write a simple REST web service for the android client to check.  That way if you wanted to for whatever reason you could move it to the cloud and do it remotely.  That is probably the simplest way I can think of as well.